# Having trouble getting page.injectJs() to work in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, headless-browser

I have the following in my code:

```
phantom.createPage(function(page){
    page.onCallback = function(data) {
        console.log("ph callback: ", data);
    };
    page.open(req.query.testUrl, function(status){
        if(status !== 'success'){
            page.close();
            res.status(500)
                .send('Page "' + testUrl + '" could not be loaded.')
                .end();
            return;
        }

        var result = page.injectJs('lib/my-test-script.js');
        console.log('injectJS: ', result);

        page.evaluate(function(){
            window.callPhantom(window.mocha.constructor.name);
        }, function(){
            console.log('finished');
            page.close();

            res.json({status: status});
            res.end();
        });
    });
});
```

And `console.log('injectJS: ', result);` is outputting "injectJS: undefined", not explicitly `false` as the docs say here:

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html

Furthermore, I've verified that my-test-script.js is there using `fs.readDir()`, yet it appears that my code isn't being injected at all, not to mention, I never get the console output from `page.onCallback()`.

I'm completely lost at this point.  I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm clueless as to what it could be.  Any help would be appreciated.

Associated [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13258).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a bridge between node.js and PhantomJS (probably [phantomjs-node](http://phantomjs-node)) so the PhantomJS docs don't apply directly.

All bridged functions (basically all PhantomJS functions) take an additional callback if they don't already to so. This is described under [Functionality details](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details) in the bridge docs. The same is true for injectJs. Also, the way you register to events is also different:

```
page.set("onCallback", function(data) {
    console.log("ph callback: ", data);
});
...
page.injectJs('lib/my-test-script.js', function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        window.callPhantom(window.mocha.constructor.name);
    }, function(){
        console.log('finished');
        page.close();

        res.json({status: status});
        res.end();
    });
});
```